# Expand nested property in one Rest url call

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, odata

Say you have a `Site` named `https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate` in the `SharePoint Online`.

I tried the url `https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists?$filter=Hidden%20eq%20false&$expand=items`. It can get all the visible `List` and the `ListItem` of them. But I also want to get all the properties including other deferred properties of `ListItem` like `File`,`RootFolder` etc. Is it possible to be done? How can I make it ?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: I tried the URL `https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPrivate/_api/Web/Lists?$select=Title,items,RootFolder&$filter=Hidden%20eq%20false&$expand=RootFolder,items/file`. Is it right ? Thanks.

Comment: How to select all the properties and expand all properties. I wonder it there is something like `*` to represent all properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [OData specification](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/):

> The syntax of a `$expand` query option is a comma-separated list of
>   Navigation Properties. Additionally each Navigation Property can be
>   followed by a forward slash and another Navigation Property to enable
>   identifying a multi-level relationship.

In your example, `List Item` resource does not expose `RootFolder` property, i guess you mean `List` resource, that case your request could look like this:

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=(Hidden eq false)&$select=Title,Items,RootFolder,Items/File&$expand=Items,Items/File,RootFolder
```

Comment: Yeah! It is a mistake. `RootFolder` is the property of `List`. :)  You are good helper. Thanks you posting the OData link.

Comment: I wondered if there is asterisk wildcard like `*` in `sql` to `$select` all properties. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang Yes, you can use "$select=*" in the GET query.